# holding the item to add changes to CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I am just want to add comments under any post and save it into CoreData, but how can I Know where am I, I don't know how to link this comment to the post I created in CoreData. I mean when I fetch data (posts) from CoreData, I want this comment to be under the correct post. look at the code, I just fill comments by normal string array. It is not dynamic and cannot be saved in CoreData as an array and retrieved to be under its post [screen shot to imagine the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x99hz.jpg)

```
struct CommentSheetView: View{
    @ObservedObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()
   // @State var showCommentsSheet : Bool
    var mainV = MainView()
    var del = Post()
   
    @ObservedObject var delegate = ViewModel()
    var body: some View{
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Spacer()
            Form{
                Section(header: Text("comments")){
                }
                ForEach(delegate.array,id :\.self) { comment in
                    Text(comment)
                }
            }.frame(height: 550)
          //  Spacer()
            Text("Type your comment below . . .")
                .font(Font.system(size: 10))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        HStack{
            TextEditor(text: $delegate.comment)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            Button(action: {
               // delegate.comments.append("Hi")
               //showCommentsSheet = false
               // mainV.fc = delegate.comment
                delegate.array.append(delegate.comment)
            }){
                Image(systemName: "paperplane.circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 100)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/1/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .background(Color(.systemGray6))
            }
                
                
        }
            Spacer()
        }.offset(y: -keyboardResponder.currentHeight*0.5).padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you add related code?

Comment: I put some changes

Comment: The code you have posted isn’t very relevant but what you need is to inject the Post object that the comments belong to into the view model for this view so that the view model can connect the created comments to that particular post.

Comment: Hello, yes that what I want, but how to reach the single post (object) in coredata to modify it? It’s in swiftUI

Comment: I assume you entered this view from another view containing Post object(s) so you should get it from there.